# Is there a way to change PHP core value (allow_url_fopen) inside PHP script?

Tags: php

Is there a way to change PHP core value "allow_url_fopen" in the PHP script?

On my hosting it is set to 'off' and I need it 'on'.

Comment: You can generally use cURL instead of anything that requires allow_url_fopen, if your hosting provider does not allow it

Answer (score 6):

[No](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen):

> Note: This setting can only be set in php.ini due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck unless you have access to the php.ini

> allow_url_fopen boolean
>
> ...
>
> Note: This setting can only be set in
> php.ini due to security reasons.

[File System Configuraion php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)